# How do I remove the line gap things after separating some meshes? (apple peeling)

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices, selection-tools

I'm trying to turn this apple into a monster like thing. I've marked 4 parts that are showed in the images, which are the parts that will peel off and the apple will move on 4 legs during my future animation. Problem is, when I separated by selection for the meshes, the black lines around the areas appeared, they are not needed and I have no idea how to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean you need the apple to keep appearing like a single object rather than several joined parts?

Comment: @moonboots What I meant was before I did any edits to the apple, it was completely round, and when I applied 4 parts to be separated for animation, the roundiness now has those black lines which you could see on the apple. I was hoping that the object will have no visual change but only visible during animating the peels. Imagine doing an explosion animation inside a cube, but you only want some parts of the cube to comes out, not the whole object, for that reason you have to separate some meshes manually. I'll try to explain more if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Yes, for an explosion it would not be a problem because you can create an original full object + the different pieces of the same object, then make the original disappear and the parts appear with some keyframes on their visibility. For your apple it's a bit more complicated, I haven't found a way yet...

Comment: @moonboots Crap, thanks for the trouble. Those lines will be like a flaw in my project I guess.

Comment: there must be a solution, a guy has made a banana peeling but the shape is not round as an apple, maybe check though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6_iZN9zbfQ&     If I think about a solution I'll tell, maybe someone will find, if you find please give the answer  ;)

Comment: This can probably be done with the Data Transfer modifier. Give me an hour or so to make some screenshots then I will post an answer.

Comment: @moonboots thanks for the vid, I saved it for the future when I will try this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Data Transfer modifier to transfer vertex normals from an uncut whole apple to an apple that has been cut up into several seperate objects, (slices).

1. To the whole uncut apple object, apply any modifers.
2. Open up the **Object Data Properties** panel and enable the **Auto Smooth** option.

Give this apple object the name *apple_whole*.

[image]

3. In Object mode make a copy of *apple_ whole*.

   Hide the "apple_whole"object.

   Give the newly created object the name "Slice"
4. Add a **Data Transfer** modifier to the *slice* object.

   The **Source Object** will be *apple_whole*.

   Enable **Face Corner Data** and select the **Projected Face Interpolation** option.

   Select **Custom Normals**.
5. In Edit mode selected the different slices and separate them into separate objects.

[image]

The the apple should now be sliced up into a number of different objects and each of these objects should have the Data Transfer modifier.

[image]

If you look carefully in the screenshots below you should be able to see the difference between a sliced apple without the Data Transfer modifier(on the left) and the sliced apple with the modifier (on the right).

[image]

[image]

Note; Thankyou to **BGibonus** (model) and **AGF81** (texture) on **Blend Swap** for providing the *Cylcle_compatable apple*, free of charge, that was used in this post.

Comment: wow interesting i'll test that

Comment: "Give the newly created object the name "Slice"", I just need to select the meshes, separate them by selection, and THEN apply the data modifier for the peel?

Comment: The idea is that at the end of step 3 (second screenshot) we have two identical objects,at exactly the same position in 3D space. The original I called "apple_whole" will be used as the source for the normal transfer. We don't need to touch this object again so we hide it so it will be easier to work on the second object. 4: This second object we add the modifier so that when in step 5 we slice it up into separate "peels" objects each object will have the modifier already added to it. You can apply the modifier to each "peel" but it is not necessary to do so.

Comment: The important thing is that the original object and the second (copy) object before and after slicing remain in exactly the same position in 3D space. So when you make the copy don't move it, instead hide the original. (disable the eye icon in the outliner)

Comment: @3fingeredfrog, nice! How would you do if you want to give thickness to the peeling? Solidify modifier works fine if you put it above the Data Transfer but the peeling edges will look sharp

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oiqRa43 Something is bugging me, when I press "Custom normals", these weird carvings appeared. I have re-done the steps 3 times to be sure, I still get the same result. Do I have to subdivide the apple again or something? Also @moonboots, I was thinking the same, also rigging the peels too so they would bend in half during walking mode. But I'll probably have to make a separate post for them for how to do it.

Comment: @lucutes the "dents" that appear on the sides of your "peeled" apple are because you have moved the peeled apple away from the source apple. Select the peeled apple and move it back along the Y axis some and you will notice the dents (shading) change and at some point will (perhaps) disapear altogether. Remember the vertex normals direction, that effect the shading are being influenced by the normals of the source object. This is why it it is very important that the peeled apple and the source apple occupy the exact same 3D position.

Comment: @moonboots I hadn't thought of the peelings needing thickness. I don't have time today but will look into that tomorrow and get back if I find a solution. First thought is to give the source apple thicknes (inner shell) then make a copy of that and slice the copy then filling in the missing edge faces of each peel object with the Bridge Edge Loops tool.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog This is yet my most complicated tutorial I have ever followed, but it worked. I brought the "Sliced apple" (it has total of 3 objects: a leaf, 4 peels as one object and the apple body) to the original, uncut "Apple whole" object's place, and the dents disappeared. I transferred the apple to my main scene, and it works fine. I just needed to import both the uncut and cut apples, parent the uncut with cut apple and I can easily animate it, like a falling apple. Not sure with the peeling animations, but I think I'll make a separate question. Thanks a lot for your sacrificed time!!!

Comment: @3fingeredfrog, actually it would rather be: keep the original with no thickness, cut the slices on the copy, with some extrusions give thickness to the parts you've created, then you can bevel the inner edges of the extruded slices to make them look smoother but I don't know how you can do it for the outer edges of the slices, giving a Subsurf would make the joints reappear

Comment: @3fingeredfrog I got a question, when applying solidify mod. should I first use the solidify modifier and THEN the data transfer? Because those black lines appeared again after I used solidification. And do I need to apply the modifiers, or can I keep them in case I want to change something?